# Nested for loops of python

Tags: python

I'm working on a nested for loop now, but something just goes wrong. As below:

```
result = [[None] * 5] *2

l = range(10) 

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(i*5, (i+1)*5):
        result[i][j%5] = l[j]

print(result)
```

But the returned result is not as expected

> [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]]

Instead I got a result of

> [[5,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,8,9]]

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `result = [[None] * 5] *2` => `result = [[[None] * 5] for _ in range (2)]`

Comment: `l = [i for i in range(10)]
    l = [l[:5], l[5:]]`